# Make: Circular ... dependency dropped

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

When compiling my Android JNI project, I got this error:

```
make: Circular /obj/local/armeabi/libstlport_static.a <- /obj/local/armeabi/libstlport_static.a dependency dropped.
```

My question is about the "dependency dropped", what's it's mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libstlport_static.a` depends upon itself. To avoid infinite loop make just ignores it.

Comment: But after, all, at least one of those get included. Right?

Comment: @Marcos: I'm not sure what you mean. You have a rule like `foo: foo`. Make will not make `foo` while already making `foo`. It shouldn't affect other dependencies but something is obviously wrong with your makefile.

Comment: Android-NDK did that, I just ignore, but I saw that stlport is still working. Thnkz